# How to download and install all available languages in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, language-pack, i18n

For testing  purposes I need to install all languages on Windows 10 and it would be nice if we have a batch script out there or bunde installer from Microsoft?

Comment: I don't know if there is an official way, but here are 
[links to the language packs](http://winaero.com/blog/download-mui-language-packs-for-windows-10-build-10586/)
 and [Add-Language pack with Powershell](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/17467cb9-d6e8-4753-8d28-91eeeca8dca1/addlanguage-pack-with-powershell?forum=win10itprosetup)

Comment: critical to use third party resources but it is at least an option.

Comment: NO, the links lead to Microsoft servers, it's just not an official collection. But if there is no other way to get the links ...

Comment: don't do this, this makes installing updates suuuuuuuuuuuuper slow.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I agree **ALL** language packs on one system is to much. OTH after updates I had to reinstall the one language pack several times and I need it only to be able to support in English.

Comment: Thanks for the warnings. I do not need updates on this machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To download all the language packs you need to have the
Windows Language Pack ISO.
If you have the MSDN, you can get it there.
If not, here is one that I found via Google -
[link](http://files.denisio.ru/iso/win10/mu_windows_10_language_pack_version_1607_updated_jul_2016_x86_x64_dvd_9058649.iso).

Once you have the ISO, open it up and copy to one folder all the language packs,
whose file-names are like `lp*.cab`.

You can install all the packs via the lpksetup command that comes with Windows:

```
lpksetup.exe /i * /p <path>
```

Some language packs require the computer to be rebooted.
For some others you do not have the right keyboard.
And I suspect that with so many packs installed, you will encounter some new
problems.

For more information :

- [Lpksetup Command-Line Options](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766010(v=ws.10).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Install-Language`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/languagepackmanagement/install-language?view=windowsserver2022-ps) PowerShell cmdlet to install some or all of the [available language packs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/available-language-packs-for-windows?view=windows-11) for your version of Windows. It will automatically fetch the language pack files over the Internet from Microsoft's servers without you having to click around in Settings hundreds of times or manually download an ISO file that is only available to OEMs, device partners, and volume license holders.

```ps1
# for Windows 10, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/available-language-packs-for-windows?view=windows-10
# all Windows 11 language packs:
$allLanguages = @("af-ZA", "am-ET", "ar-SA", "as-IN", "az-Latn-AZ", "be-BY",
    "bg-BG", "bn-IN", "bs-Latn-BA", "ca-ES", "ca-ES-valencia", "chr-CHER-US",
    "cs-CZ", "cy-GB", "da-DK", "de-DE", "el-GR", "en-GB", "en-US", "es-ES",
    "es-MX", "et-EE", "eu-ES", "fa-IR", "fi-FI", "fil-PH", "fr-CA", "fr-FR",
    "ga-IE", "gd-GB", "gl-ES", "gu-IN", "he-IL", "hi-IN", "hr-HR", "hu-HU",
    "hy-AM", "id-ID", "is-IS", "it-IT", "ja-JP", "ka-GE", "kk-KZ", "km-KH",
    "kn-IN", "kok-IN", "ko-KR", "lb-LU", "lo-LA", "lt-LT", "lv-LV", "mi-NZ",
    "mk-MK", "ml-IN", "mr-IN", "ms-MY", "mt-MT", "nb-NO", "ne-NP", "nl-NL",
    "nn-NO", "or-IN", "pa-IN", "pl-PL", "pt-BR", "pt-PT", "quz-PE", "ro-RO",
    "ru-RU", "sk-SK", "sl-SI", "sq-AL", "sr-Cyrl-BA", "sr-Cyrl-RS", "sr-Latn-RS",
    "sv-SE", "ta-IN", "te-IN", "th-TH", "tr-TR", "tt-RU", "ug-CN", "uk-UA",
    "ur-PK", "uz-Latn-UZ", "vi-VN", "zh-CN", "zh-TW")

echo "Installing $($allLanguages.Count) languages"

foreach ($language in $allLanguages) {
    if ((Get-InstalledLanguage $language).Count -eq 0) {
        echo "Installing language $language"
        Install-Language $language -ExcludeFeatures
    } else {
        echo "Skipping language $language because it is already installed"
    }
}

echo "There are $((Get-InstalledLanguage).Count) languages installed"
```

To see which language packs are installed, you can run [`Get-InstalledLanguage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/languagepackmanagement/get-installedlanguage?view=windowsserver2022-ps):

```ps1
PS> Get-InstalledLanguage

Language Language Packs  Language Features
-------- --------------  -----------------
af-ZA    LXP             BasicTyping
am-ET    LXP             BasicTyping
ar-SA    LpCab           BasicTyping, OCR
...
```

You can also count how many language packs are currently installed:

```ps1
PS> (Get-InstalledLanguage).Count
108
```

Installing every language pack takes dozens of gigabytes of drive space and dozens of hours, even with a fast internet connection, CPU, and SSD.

The Valencia language interface pack (`ca-ES-valencia`) never seems to install successfully.